# Method of moment for beta-binomial distribution.

Tags: empirical-bayes

In empirical bayes methods, we can estimate hyper-parameter from using data.

In hierachical model,
random vector $X = (X_1,X_2)^T \ where \ X_i=(X_{11},\cdots,X_{1k})^T, i\in{1,2} \\
X|p_{i} \sim binomial(n,p_i) \\ p_i|\lambda \sim beta(\alpha,\beta)$

Then Marginal distribution $ p_i|\alpha,\beta \sim^{iid} betabinomial(\alpha,\beta) $

I want to calculate the method of moments for hyper parameter $\alpha, \beta$

Since IID, I can have first method of moment by calculating $EX = \bar X $

here, I'm confusing.

In empirical bayes, estimated hyperparameter can incorporate the information about $p_1,p_2$

But, $EX_1 = \bar X_1, EX_2 = \bar X_2$

Although $EX_1 = EX_2 $, I think, $ \bar X_1 \ne \bar X_2 $ for observed values.

I don't know how informations are incoporated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.